# MySQL slow avg min max using filesort

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

How can i optimize query, its taking about 2 sec already, with about 500k records in 'resulta' table, but I expect that touble to grow to sevaral billions.

```
 SELECT
     hopcount, hop, round( avg( rtt ) , 2 ) AS avg, min( rtt ) AS min, max( rtt ) AS        max
FROM results
JOIN traces ON id = trace
WHERE target =9
AND rtt > -1
GROUP BY hop`
```

Explain output:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   SIMPLE  traces  ref PRIMARY,fk_traces_1_idx fk_traces_1_idx 5   const   26333   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort  
1   SIMPLE  results ref trace   trace   5   pinger.traces.id    7   Using where
```

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `results` (
  `hop` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trace` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rtt` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `seq` int(11) NOT NULL,
  KEY `trace` (`trace`),
  KEY `fk_hops_id` (`hop`),
  KEY `seq` (`seq`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;  
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `traces` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `hopcount` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `target` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_traces_1_idx` (`target`,`id`,`time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=52308;
```

Comment: you'd probably be able to optimise this further if you better defined your clustered primary keys. Take a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-index-types.html and http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/07/04/how-to-exploit-mysql-index-optimizations/ Hope it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL, `GROUP BY` implies `ORDER BY`

To remove this implicit sort, add `ORDER BY NULL`

This is mentioned in the [MySQL docs for SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)

> If you use GROUP BY, output rows are sorted according to the GROUP BY columns as if you had an ORDER BY for the same columns. To avoid the overhead of sorting that GROUP BY produces, add ORDER BY NULL:

And also in [ORDER BY Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html)

Comment: Thanks, that dropped time from 2 sec to 1.3 and not using filesort anymore, but it still looks slow to me. Any more ideas how to optimize it?

Comment: I'd like to be proved wrong, but short of creating dedicated summary tables, I think that's as good as you're going to get it.

Comment: All involved columns are indexed, IMHO
Talking about summary tables - problem is that 'results' table could be updated every second and those min max should include latest results. Probably it is possible to summarize older values somehow...